# Comparando variável digitada pelo usuário com variável do arquivo

Tags: c, arquivo, comparação

Dentro do meu arquivo `arquivo.txt` eu guardo duas strings `"nome"` e `"senha"`, elas ficam uma em baixo da outra.

**Eu preciso pegar o nome e a senha digitado pelo usuário e comparar com o nome e a senha que tenho guardado no arquivo.txt**

*OBS: A informação abaixo do EOF, eu já tentei fazer != NULL, mas ficou em um loop infinito.*

Eu fiz um `while`, para que `enquanto for diferente de EOF`, ele rodar...
Como eu não encontrei um jeito de comparar as variáveis digitadas com as do arquivo, eu chamei o `strcpy`. 
Criei mais duas variáveis char e copiei o `nome` e a `senha` que foram digitados pelo usuário para `string2` e `string3`. ***Para que então eu possa comparar o `nome` com a `string2` e a `senha` com a `string3`***.

Mas aparece sempre um aviso que não estou conseguindo entender.

```
warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char' *', but argument 3 has type 'char'(*)[100]'
```

Entendo o que esta escrito, mas não entendo o que isso interfere no código.

**O erro que da no programa é o seguinte: Tudo que eu digito, ele entra como verdadeiro, entra no if e imprime Bem-Vindo!**

```
FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("arquivo.txt", "r");

    if (fp == NULL) {

        printf("\nO arquivo não foi aberto!");
        exit(0);

    }

    char nome[100], senha[100], string2[100],string3[100]; 

    printf("\n\tNOME........: ");
    scanf("%s", nome);
    //Tentei fazer com fgets, mas da erro quando uso no while, então
    //resolvi deixar o scanf mesmo

    printf("\n\tSENHA........: ");
    scanf("%s", senha);

    printf("\n");

// printf("\n%s %s", nome, senha); //testar o que foi digitado pelo usuario

    printf("\n");

    while( (fscanf(fp, "%s %s", &nome, &senha)) != EOF ) {

        strcpy(string2, nome);
        strcpy(string3, senha);

        if ( (strcmp(nome, string2) == 0) && (strcmp(senha, string3) == 0) ) {

            printf("\nBem-Vindo!\n");


        } else {

            printf("\nSeu login ou senha estão errados!");

        }

    }

    }

    fclose(fp);

}
```

Comment: No seu `fscanf` você está armazenando o que está no arquivo dentro de `nome` e `senha` e não dentro de `string2` e `string3`.

Comment: Nossa, DaviAragao ... Muito obrigada. Há muito tempo eu estava parada nesse erro e não entendi a porquê. Procurei em vários lugares e não encontrava... Deu super certo aqui. Obrigada mesmo. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A condição do teu while devia ser

```
//while( (fscanf(fp, "%s %s", &nome, &senha)) != EOF ) {
while ((fscanf(fp, "%s%s", nome, senha)) == 2) {
```

As diferenças são

- uso de `&` nas variaveis
  usar o `&` especifica endereço do array (tipo `char(*)[100]`)
  sem o `&` o tipo é automaticamente convertido para `char*`
- em vez de testar se o resultado for diferente de `EOF`, o teste para ser igual a 2 cobre mais situações que podem ser erro.
- o espaço entre os dois `%s` é desnecessário
- formatação a meu gosto :-)

Comment: Ah sim, agora entendi o porque de dar aquele aviso...Eu estava indicando o endereço da variável e não seu valor. Eu segui agora o que o DaviAragão me ensinou ali em cima, e deu certo... Então, eu posso fazer tanto do jeito dele quanto do seu jeito que no final, o resultado é o mesmo?

Comment: Como o @DaviAragao reparou, deves user `string2` e `string3` em vez de `nome` e `senha` e deixar de fazer a cópia. `fscanf(fp, "%s%s", string2, string3)`

Comment: Ah sim, ok...Obrigada. ;)

Answer (score 4):

A resposta do @pmg elimina o *warning* ao compilar. Porém tem um erro de lógica no teu código. Ao ler os arquivos do arquivo você está sobrescrevendo os valores que o usuário informou como `usuario` e `senha`. Armazene o que está no arquivo dentro de `string2` e `string3`.

Comment: Eu não entendi muito bem. Fiz o que me disse ali em cima e ele está rodando de um jeito certo. Pelo menos ao meu ver (sou iniciante). rs Quando você diz "Armazene o que está no arquivo dentro de string2 e string3", você quer dizer pra eu na linha depois do while copiar os valores do nome e senha na string2 e string3? Devo usar o strcpy para isso também?